# C++ STL "Association Set/Map"

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, dictionary, set

I'm looking for the name of a particular kind of set/map, for which there is hopefully some existing code, such as the C++ STL.

Call the set `A`.

I would like to run the following commands:

```
A.associate(3,5)
A.associate(3,6)
A.associate(6,8)
A.associate(8,10)
A.associate(4,9)
```

And then be able to ask the following questions, receiving the answers indicated:

```
A.is_associated(3,5)  -> True
A.is_associated(5,10) -> True
A.is_associated(10,3) -> True
A.is_associated(4,10) -> False
```

Do you know the name of this kind of construct/set?

Do you know if there is an existing C/C++ implementation?

Comment: Why is `A.is_associated(5,10)` true? Could you please explain the association logic in more detail?

Comment: The sequence `5->3->6->8->10`.

Comment: It seems as no one of the answerers understood the question :/

Comment: Ah, so it's a bidirectional association and one can follow the chain as much as needed. Yes, I would call that an undirected graph. I will delete my answer. OP, in future please be more careful about explaining your requirements.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure, I felt the question was clear, without presuming to propose an underlying structure and possibly bias the answers. My apologies if you were working on an answer for it - thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** if you want to go the extra step, you should think about an efficient implementation of [Disjoint-set Union-Find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Unfortunately the only sane way I see is making a `std::map` over `std::sets` -- you need to check each time at insert, whether the two elements are in different subsets -- if so, you merge them.

So the outer set stores all elements and points them to the sets they belong to.

Now if you add a new association:

1. check to which sets do A and B belong to
2. if neither belongs to any set, create a new set and map both values to that set (end)
3. if one belongs to a set and the other doesn't, put the other into the first ones set and map it there (end)
4. if both belong to different sets, merge the sets and update the elements mappings accordingly.

Now the is_associated function is really fast -- just check if the two elements belong to the same set.

In english:

```
typedef std::map< int, std::set< int >& > assoc_set; // note that you need to 
                 // store the sets somewhere else, maybe in another set
```

Something maybe like this:

```
class assoc_set
{
    typedef std::set< int > int_set;
    typedef std::set< int_set > int_set_set;
    typedef std::map< int, int_set_set::iterator > set_map;
public:
    void associate( int a, int b )
    {
        set_set_map::iterator ia = iss.find( a );
        set_set_map::iterator ib = iss.find( b );
        if ( ia == set_set_map::end() )
        {
            if ( ib == set_set_map::end() )
            {
                // create new
                int_set ab;
                ab.insert(a);
                ab.insert(b);
                int_set_set::iterator r = iss.insert( ab ).second;
                smap[a] = r;
                smap[b] = r;
            }
            else
            {
                // add to a
                smap[a] = ib;
                ib->insert( a );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( ib == set_set_map::end() )
            {
                // add to b
                smap[b] = ia;
                ia->insert( b );
            }
            else
            {
                // merge
                ia->insert( ib->begin(), ib->end() );
                // this could be done better
                for ( int_set::iterator i = it->begin(); i != it->end(); ++i )
                {
                    smap[*i] = ia;
                }

            }

        }


    }

    bool is_associated( int a, int b )
    {
        set_set_map::iterator ia = iss.find( a );
        set_set_map::iterator ib = iss.find( b );

        return ia != set_set_map::end() && ia = ib;
    }

private:
    int_set_set iss;
    set_map smap;
}
```

There will be errors and bugs, I have just notepad available (and spent too much time on this anyway).

Adding is `O(n)` (but might be reduced to `O(log(n))` by using an additional layer of indirection (and getting rid of the stupid map loop). Query is `O(log(n))`.

Using `unordered_set/unordered_map` you might reduce both to `O(1)` amortized.

Answer (score 8):

In general I think this data structure is a graph: that is, a set of nodes which are in your case identified using integer, and a set of edges which are possibly directed pairs of nodes. There are many ways to represent and graphs depending on your specific needs. Boost has a number of typical graph data structure plus a collection of algorithms operating on them.

Based on some the clarifications in the comments: the `is_associated()` operation is a path search in an undirected graph. Depending on the graph's need, adding edge can be made to represent the data structure such that `is_associated()` is constant time at the cost of insertion costing linear time.

Comment: This solution is good if you want fast and light construction, but you're willing to accept slow querying. If you want fast querying (at a cost of slower construction and more space requirements) you'd better go with a map of sets.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz You can do either: if you want have many changes and few queries, you would to a path search each time. If you have many queries and few changes, you can set up the graph upon change: there are many ways to represent graphs tailored to specific news. In fact, a map of set is isomorphic to a graph.

Comment: Come to think of it, this is not a graph, but a disjoint-set.

Comment: Yes, [Union Find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) may be something useful. I tend to view this a a graph algorithm used e.g. in the all-pair shortest path.